# CreateJS : Listen for particular frame in Sprite animation or obtain frame label index?

Tags: label, sprite, frame, createjs

Is there any API to listen for a particular frame during an animation of a Sprite in CreateJS?  There was kind of a way to trigger events at particular frames in a Flash MovieClip, but not sure how to do this in CreateJS.

I could achieve this by listening to the change event of the Sprite while it animates, check the currentFrame on each event, check if the frame index is the one to which I want to react, BUT, this seems rather laboured, and means I have to hard code to an index instead of a frame label.

Interestingly, the `_animations` property of a Sprite seems to be intended to be private, so although I can use this property to ascertain the length of the animation, again, would still have to hard code to a index value.  (Out of curiosity, why not have mySprite.length() API?  Flash's MovieClip has a number of frames prop...).

Is there a way to make frame labels in CreateJS?  [In the docs here](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Sprite.html), I can see the use of:

```
instance.gotoAndStop("frameName");
```

...but I don't see any documentation on how to *set* frame labels in a SpriteSheet for a particular animation sequence, or how to retrieve the index of the frame associated with a frame label.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `gotoAndStop` and `gotoAndPlay` methods both allow for a frame number or animation name (not frame name). You can label animations when you create a [SpriteSheet](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/SpriteSheet.html), but you can not otherwise make named keyframes inside of animations.

To determine the keyframe, you could check the `currentAnimationFrame` ([doc](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Sprite.html#property_currentAnimationFrame)) on your main tick function, or listen for the `change` event ([doc](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Sprite.html#event_change)) from the Sprite.

```
sprite.on("tick", function() {
    if (sprite.currentAnimationFrame == 10) { 
        // do something
    }
});
```

Note that depending on your app framerate, you might have to store the previous frame, and check if the playhead has *passed* a certain frame, as EaselJS may skip frames depending on the speed of playback.

--

The `length` property is a good idea, but it would likely have to be a method that you pass in an animation name. I have logged an [issue](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/626) on the EaselJS GitHub